# Общий вопрос по JavaScript - html-свойство editable

Tags: javascript, html5, form

Я в js вообще абсоноль :(.

Если на странице имеется, например `<textarea>`, но пользователь не видит самого поля, а просто видит текст в нем.

Можно ли при помощи js установить свойство элемента `editable` - если такое вообще существует, и в результате получить форму для редактирования и отправки данных? (+после нажатия кнопки `изменить`, показать кнопку `send`)

Поле `<textarea>` изначально находится в `<form>`.

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы когда пользователь кликал кнопку включало редактирование поля, потом пользователь нажимал "сохранить" и после этого поле уже не редактировалось?

Comment: ну да. После нажатия сенд или сохранить - происходит обычна отправка формы на сервер.

Comment: А в чём сложность? Сделать возможность редактирование textarea или отправки формы? Или всё вместе?

Comment: я в общем спрашиваю: Возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: Можно. Делаем кнопку редактировать, после нажатие на которую редактируется textarea и появляются кнопка сохранить. Нажимаем на кнопку сохранить - отправляется форма. Так?

Comment: да. так. :(( придется изучать js. Решения НЕ нужно - я спрашивал можно ли так сделать на js.

Comment: Не огорчайтесь. Для начала можете библиотекой jquery попользоваться, а потом уже на чистый переходить

Comment: я не хочу никаких библиотек. Это будет выглядеть (относительно js) так как-будто я изучаю php, пользуясь воррдпресом или иными CMS. :( много всего хочу. главное правильно расставить приоритеты.